# Aligning DIV to the right

Tags: css, html, css-float

Im using a set of layers, with this CSS

```
.left1 {
    float: left;
    left: 5px;
    width: 72px;
    height: 100px;
}
.left2 {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: 186px;
}
.eventCat {
    float: right;
    width: 5px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

to make inline divs. however, when i add a layer that i wish to be align to the right, it seems to fall below (the green one `.eventCat`). It should be at the right hand side of the red box! even with `float:right;` what am i missing?

I made a fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/7GBca/ to fiddle with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not floating correctly because `.float2` is not floted, my guess is you want it to expand to fill all available width and that's why you didn't set an explicit width. One solution to align `.eventCat` correctly would be to use `position:absolute;` and use `right:0;`

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative; 
}
.eventCat {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 5px;
    height: 100%;
}
.left2 {
    padding-right: 5px; /*set this to the width of .eventCat so it does not overlap*/
}
```

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7GBca/9/embedded/result/)**

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this is set a negative top margin to your green div:

```
.eventCat {
  margin: -100px 0 0 0;
  float: right;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7GBca/4/)

Answer (score 0):

you are missing "width: ...px" and "float: left" of 'left2' and "width: ...px" of 'wrapper'.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is fixed, please check the code here:

```
<style type="text/css">
.eventCat {
float: right;
width: 5px;
height: 100px;
}
.eventIMG {
float: left;
left: 0;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
.left1 {
float: left;
left: 5px;
width: 72px;
height: 100px;
}
.left2 {
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
margin-left: 186px;
}
.set:hover {
background-color: #FFDEAD;
cursor: pointer;
cursor: hand;
}
#event.title {
font-size: 21px;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}
#event {
color: black;
}
</style>
```

and here is your HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="eventIMG" style="background:url('http://hqhq.dk/beta/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/png-5.jpg') no-repeat scroll center center / 100% auto transparent"></div>
  <div class="left1">
    <div style="text-transform: uppercase;">WED 18.09</div>
    <div style="text-transform: uppercase;">kl.22.00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="eventCat" style="background-color:green;"></div>
  <div class="left2" id="event">
    <div id="event" class="title"><a class="url" href="http://hqhq.dk/beta/event/fuzz-manta-dron/" title="FUZZ MANTA + DRÖN" rel="bookmark">FUZZ MANTA + DRÖN</a></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="">
      <p>something here</p>
      <a href="http://hqhq.dk/beta/event/fuzz-manta-dron/" class="" rel="bookmark">Find out more »</a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="eventIMG" style="background:url('http://hqhq.dk/beta/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/png-5.jpg') no-repeat scroll center center / 100% auto transparent"></div>
  <div class="left1">
    <div style="text-transform: uppercase;">WED 18.09</div>
    <div style="text-transform: uppercase;">kl.22.00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="eventCat" style="background-color:green;"></div>
  <div class="left2" id="event">
    <div id="event" class="title"><a class="url" href="http://hqhq.dk/beta/event/fuzz-manta-dron/" title="FUZZ MANTA + DRÖN" rel="bookmark">FUZZ MANTA + DRÖN</a></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="">
      <p>something here</p>
      <a href="http://hqhq.dk/beta/event/fuzz-manta-dron/" class="" rel="bookmark">Find out more »</a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What you have to do there is to replace you div.eventCat with div.left2 that's it :-)

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KRU9U/

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Put the `eventCat` (the element you want to float to the right) as the first element under `wrapper`.